# Manhwa where mc has skill steal or duplication ability, and takes a speech type ability form a girl while in a dungeon

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I read this manhwa a while ago, I don't remember much but in one chapter the mc goes in either a dungeon or tower and the floor they were on was a maze the group he was with had I think 3 other guys and 1 girl who has a speech ability he takes but in order to take skills he needed to spend time with her so he proposedly spent a couple days with her avoiding the exit, eventually a minotaur shows up and he kills it. I remember the girl not liking mc and becoming sort of traumatized cause they didn't pack enough food to be stuck for so long, also the other guys may have died.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When was "a while ago?"  A year, 5 years?  Where did you read it?  Do you remember any of the details of the art?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [I'm the max level newbie](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/im-the-max-level-newbie).
The protagonist is the only one to finish a really hard RPG, and after he finishes the game it appears in reality. When he first enters the game he goes to a dungeon that only he knows of (nobody played the game for very long, as it was deemed to difficult). 
The girl (with a skill called communion that makes peoble like her) and 3 guys follow him and try to take advantage of him, but the guys die and he steals the skill from the girl. In the dungeon is a minotaur, which the protagonist uses to improve his stats.