# What was the manhwa of a guy who beat a game and the game became reality

Tags: story-identification, manga

I didn't read much of it, but I remember that there was this one game that when it was launched, it was really popular. But due to the game being too hard, it lost popularity with time. But there was this guy who kept playing the game for years until he was finally able to complete and beat the game. When that happened, the real world became the game and the first level was something about a tree, and there was an apple I think. I don't remember a lot besides that, but I think the guy went into a cave where there were other people, and that's all I read.

I doubt that I explained well, but if anyone thinks they know what I'm talking, about please tell me the name.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

*[Max Level Newbie](https://max-level-newbie.fandom.com/wiki/Kang_Jinhyuk)* by B.Ain as per [this video review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoGJ9MWMveY):

> The main character, Jin Hyuk, was a game newtuber and the only one who saw the ending of the [Tower of Trials]. But the popularity of the game has subsided, and it has become difficult to lead the life of a gaming newtuber. After seeing the ending, Jin Hyuk was going to finish the game. On that day, the [Tower of Trials] became a reality. Jin Hyuk, who knows all the components of the game, takes over everything faster than anyone: "I'll show you what a real old man is."

Found with a search for `manhwa man beats game years after it stopped being popular, and it takes over the world`

Comment: Also the unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266795/manhwa-where-mc-has-skill-steal-or-duplication-ability-and-takes-a-speech-type/266803#266803