# Manhwa where a gaming Nutuber who saw the ending is pulled into the world

Tags: story-identification, manga

Hero, a gaming Nutuber, was the only person who saw the ending of the game [Tower of Trials]. However, when the game's popularity declined, it became difficult for him to continue making a living as a gaming Nutuber. Since he already saw the ending of the game, he was about to quit playing. But that day, [Tower of Trials] became reality, and Hero, who knew about every single thing in the game, took over everything faster than anyone possibly could! "I'll show you what a true pro is like."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: That is a direct quote of the Amazon synopsis for *[Solo Max-Level Newbie](https://www.amazon.com/Solo-Max-Level-Newbie/dp/B09XH7G1P5)*.

Answer (score 1):

*[Solo Max-Level Newbie](https://wuxiaworld.eu/novel/solo-max-level-newbie)* by Maslow and Swing Bat

That is almost a direct quote of the synopsis of the series.

> Jinhyuk, a gaming Nutuber, was the only person who saw the ending of the game [Tower of Trials]. However, when the game’s popularity declined, it became difficult for him to continue making a living as a gaming Nutuber. Since he already saw the ending of the game, he was about to quit playing. But that day, [Tower of Trials] became reality, and Jinhyuk, who knew about every single thing in the game, took over everything faster than anyone possibly could! “I’ll show you what a true pro is like.”

According to [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/147392/Im_the_Max-Level_Newbie), it's published in English by Tappytoon and Webtoon Entertainment.

[Official English site](https://www.webtoons.com/en/action/im-the-max-level-newbie/list?title_no=3915&webtoon-platform-redirect=true) under the title of *I'm the Max-Level Newbie*

Comment: Also the unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266795/manhwa-where-mc-has-skill-steal-or-duplication-ability-and-takes-a-speech-type and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/283389/what-was-the-manhwa-of-a-guy-who-beat-a-game-and-the-game-became-reality

Comment: You should link to the [official English version](https://m.webtoons.com/en/action/im-the-max-level-newbie/list?title_no=3915) and mention that variation of the title.